# Chain Rule for Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am having trouble seeing how the chain rule gives the following result when used to solve a second order PDE.

Here are the two given characteristic equations

$E = y - x^2$ and $N = y$

We were also given the first derrivative with respect to x and asked to use the chain rule to find the second derrivative. I do not see how they got the answer they did.

$\Phi_x = -2x\Phi_E $

$\Phi_{xx}= ? $

My working gave me the follwing $\Phi_{xx} = (-2x\Phi_{EE})(-2x) = 4x^2\Phi_{EE}$

The given solution was $-2\Phi_E + 4x^2\Phi_{EE}$

Can someone explain how they got the additional term ?

Thank you

Comment: $\partial_x (-2x \Phi_E) = -2\partial_x x \Phi_E - (-2x)\partial_x \Phi_E = -2 \Phi_E+ \ldots$

Comment: @higgs , when using chain rule here though its $\frac{\Phi_x}{dE}$.$\frac{dE}{dx}$ right.

Comment: You are required to find $\Phi_{xx}$, the tricky part comes when you try to take the derivative with respect to $x$ on $\Phi_{E}$, you can just easily take the derivative with respect to $x$ of anything in $x$ without a change of variable needed.

Comment: @higgs Wait so that would mean, using the product rule I would get $\Phi_{xx} = (-2\Phi_{E}) + (- 2x\Phi_{EE})(-2x) = -2\Phi_E + 4x^2\Phi_{EE}$, which is the correct solution.

Comment: Exactly right, nice one.